# Extending Jekyll and Liquid to parse post's content

Tags: liquid, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

My blog, powerred by [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/), serves out a [Atom](http://stefan.artspace44.com/atom.xml) feed.

```
---
layout: nill
rooturi: http://stefan.artspace44.com
---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

...

{% for post in site.posts %}
  <entry>
    <title>{{ post.title }}</title>
    <link href="{{ page.rooturi }}{{ post.url }}" />
    <updated>{{post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
    <id>{{ page.rooturi }}{{ post.id }}</id>
    <content type="html">{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</content>
  </entry>
 {% endfor %}
</feed>
```

I need to change the **content** of each post, so that

```
<img href="/images/01.jpg" />
<a href="/2010/post/">Post</a>
```

**becomes:**

```
<img href="http://stefan.artspace44.com/images/01.jpg" />
<a href="http://stefan.artspace44.com/2010/post/">Post</a>
```

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of

```
<content type='html'>
  {{ post.content | make_hrefs_base page.rooturi }}
</content>
```

Where would I code this in [jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/) or [liquid](http://github.com/tobi/liquid), and how could I solve the problem of changing only the **href** values that point to "/*" and not "http://otherdomain.com/*"?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where would I code this in jekyll or liquid?

In the recently-released Jekyll 0.6.0, you can create your own plugins, including Liquid tag plugins. You can check out the [Jekyll plugin](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/plugins) documentation for more info, but that would be your best bet.

> How could I solve the problem of changing only the href values that point to "/" and not "http://otherdomain.com/"?

Seems pretty easy. In your custom Liquid tag, check to see if the first character is a '/'; if it is, then prepend your new domain. You could probably use a Ruby HTML parser to find all instances of `<a>`, and then change the `href` attributes as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in [the feed of my blog](http://christianspecht.de/feed/atom/index.xml), and I managed to solve it without using a plugin, i.e. only with vanilla Liquid.

In [my Atom XML file](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/9c3268951748c408d4cc6edeb496f5ed9af4748e/src/feed/atom/index.xml?at=default), my content is populated like this:

```
<content type="html">
    {{ post.content | replace: site.feed_linkurl_find, site.feed_linkurl_replace | replace: site.feed_imgurl_find, site.feed_imgurl_replace | xml_escape }}
</content>
```

...and I have these variables in [my config file](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/9c3268951748c408d4cc6edeb496f5ed9af4748e/_config.yml?at=default):

```
# URL replacements for feeds
feed_linkurl_find: href="/
feed_linkurl_replace: href="http://christianspecht.de/
feed_imgurl_find: src="/
feed_imgurl_replace: src="http://christianspecht.de/
```

---

In other words, I just do two [ordinary string replaces](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#replace), one for links and one for images.

**The trick is:

In both cases, I replace `href="/` by `href="http://christianspecht.de/`, so only those links that actually *begin* with `/` are affected.**